# The .affix-bottom class doesn't work for the twitter bootstrap affix plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I've tried many syntaxes with data-attributes and Javascript syntax in order to get the .affix-bottom class set for the affixed object when I scroll down, but it doesn't work.
When I inspect the affixed element, the .affix class doesn't change into .affix-bottom when I reach the bottom of the page by scrolling down.

I've tried a lot of snippets inclluding those provided in the official documentation:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  ...
</div>
```

====

```
$('#my-affix').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

Have I missed something?

THank's in advance.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup too -- or create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Your div should be like this

`<div id="my-affix">`

Since you're refering to that div id in jQuery.
The affix js wasn't listening the html data elements for me either, but this should work!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you set `data-offset-bottom="200"` directly in your HTML tags already.

Since you didn't set the id in your HTML tags, there's no way your jQuery selector could get that element.

To make this works:
1. Add id to your element
2. Remove both `data-offset-top` and `data-offset-bottom` if you are going to calculate the bottom dynamically.

So the result would be something like this:

```
<div id="my-affix" data-spy="affix">
  ...
</div>
 ...
<div class="footer></div>
====

$('#my-affix').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100
    , bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```